# Sound lags behind video stream in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, video-streaming

How to adjust a +- 1-2 second lag when video streaming. I have found no solution yet. Help appreciated.

Comment: Of course you will experience lag running unspecified video streaming on an an unspecified computer, running unspecified other tasks, with unspecified resources available.  Do you have any other questions?

Comment: There is actually a solution - please don't close, I'm writing an answer...

Comment: Piet: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the answer below, which means Yes, this answer is valid! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In **PulseAudio Volume Control**, in the tab **Output Devices**,
expand the section **Advanced** for the output device in question.

You can set a **latency offset** as millisecond value in the advanced section of each device.
That value can be positive or negative;  There are other options in the advanced section that may be related to the synchronisation with video.

[image]

There are changes in the synchronisation that **need support from the video player** side, because the player can show the video before even delivering the audio data to the audio system. So it is not clear **whether the problem can be solved** with the player you use, or a **different video player**.

Note that **reducing lag of sound** may be possible by **reducing internal default latency** delays.

Comment: **Piet**:  As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**